# Another word for a "selective" character trait

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm seeking the word that describes a character trait for someone who, when given a system of beliefs, methods, or views, will sort through and accept or emulate only the best or purposeful parts of the system, while disregarding the irrational, superfluous, or unnecessary parts of said system.

I'm looking for adjective, used to describe the tendency of a person to act in a certain manner.  I believe it ends in the suffix *-ive*, though I cannot be sure.

> "Arya may see the purpose of their system of beliefs and the good that they do, yet she often argues at the inconsistent narratives and irrational acceptance of blind faith that such views require.  She can be very ____ in matters such as these."

I'm looking for a neutral connotation.

Further context (long shot): it is used in one of the *Inheritance Cycle* books for one of the main characters, Eragon, to describe his love interest Arya, in a similar manner as posted above.  I simply cannot find or remember the exact wording, or the chapter that it was used in, even though I have searched the definition of this word before.

A synonym for such a trait, used as a verb, would be "to cherry-pick".

e.g. "Bob likes to go to church, but when it comes to the Bible, he cherry-picks what to believe and what not to believe."

Further to a [comment provided by Carly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494297/character-trait-for-someone-who-selectively-adopts-only-some-elements-of-a-syste#comment1193154_494297), the English adjective I'm looking for is also likely to match the Japanese concept of [*iitoko-dori*](https://nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/109426/iitokodori).

Comment: theres a perfect japanese term for it: iitoko-dori.  good luck in your search. https://www.nihongomaster.com/dictionary/entry/109426/iitokodori

Comment: I have rolled back the question title. The edit made to it was a kind of subtle way of presupposing the answer to the question. Changes to it should be done in such a way as to not turn it into a, literally, leading question.

Comment: @Chappo I was going to suggest _selective_ until I read your comment. Did the original version of the question specifically exclude it?

Comment: @BoldBen Exactly. Personally, my immediate answer would also be *selective*. (I disagree that it's inappropriate.) But, seeing it in the title, I would presume that it was a word that was *not* desired by the OP. At this point, I can only wait to have the OP comment on *selective*.

Comment: @chappo Unless it's the OP who is adding a word, I don't think that anybody should pick *any* word that might be an answer. (And it doesn't matter if you think it's the right answer or not.) Nobody would tend to suggest it because the assumption would be that, since it is in the question, it is not a desired answer. It should really be the OP to make this kind of wording edit.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective [**selective**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/selective) fits your description. It ends in -ive and matches the meaning you want the word you're looking for to have. The Oxford Dictionary gives this adjective, among other meanings, the following definition:

> (of a person) tending to choose carefully

Example sentence:

> He is very **selective** in his reading.

Comment: Selective is good as it also relates to the (more formal) problem of selection bias in data analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias

Answer (score 1):

FOUND IT!

> **[Eclectic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic)**
>   adjective
>   eclec·​tic | \ i-ˈklek-tik, e-\
>
> Definition of eclectic (Entry 1 of 2)
>
> 1. composed of elements drawn from various sources
>      *also*: **heterogeneous**
> 2. selecting what appears to be best in various doctrines, methods, or styles

EDIT: or another possibility would be Syncretic, however it infers an amalgamation of all of the doctrines, instead of taking what is desired from each.

---

**Note on other answers**

I must apologize for the misleading "-ive" suffix that I had originally assumed that the word contained.

@Mike R - While *selective* does, in a broad sense, cover the grounds of the word I was looking for, it does not pertain specifically to sets of ideals.  One can be selective about anything, including vocabulary and semantics. :p

@listeneva - While *discriminating* does fit the definition that I was looking for, I feel that it can carry a negative connotation that does not work well when describing one who accepts and emulates the best of different ideals and philosophies.  Also, Slate Magazine is being a little one sided there.  Girls can be just as discriminating, if not more so, for their play things. ;)

Comment: Glad you've found it. Just so you know, though, _discriminating_ does not "carry a negative connotation". Here's its definition from an Oxford Dictionary: "Having or showing refined taste or good judgement." It doesn't carry such a negative connotation associated with _discriminatory_ or _discriminate_. Speaking of a negative connotation, "Cherry picking has a negative connotation as the practice neglects, overlooks or directly suppresses evidence that could lead to a complete picture." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking

Comment: @listeneva - while what you're saying is certainly true in the traditional or objective sense, we must always remember that the connotation of language is primarily derived from social trends and understandings.  Currently, to call oneself "discriminating" could lead to some unfortunate social misinterpretations; as discrimination is such a HUGE social issue.

Comment: @ listeneva (continued) - Also, it seems to me that trying to tell me that discriminating is not negative, yet cherry picking is, after offering discriminating as an answer, and telling me that one neglects and overlooks while the other does not, is rather contradictory. Also, this is why I was seeking the word eclectic, as it infers that one has already considered the entirety of a "picture" yet emulates or selects only the best parts.  After all, no one wants to eat rotten cherries.

Comment: *Eclectic* doesn't commonly convey the meaning you're going for of evaluating and picking the best parts. Most people use it to mean diverse or wide-ranging, with a hint that the choices are peculiar or unusual.  That secondary meaning discusses a particular philosophical branch, Eclecticism, which does do what you're asking about, but is not widely known.

Comment: If this answer were from anyone else, I would be tempted to vote it down for not answering the question! (I don't think this word means what you think it does.)

Comment: NB: our site positively *welcomes* you to post an answer to your own question – you even earn a special badge if it scores 3+. However, I've edited out your message to the moderators; if you want a mod to take action, you need to raise a *flag*. I've therefore raised a flag on your answer, to pass on your message to them.

Comment: I'm glad you found the word you were looking for, not being able to find the one you want can drive you crazy! I hadn't encountered the specific philosophical / religious meaning of eclectic before following your link (even though the Oxofrd dictionary shows it to be the original). However the [Oxford definition 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eclectic) is slightly different from the Merriam Webster one and emphasises its application to ancient philosophers rather than to modern religious seekers so, even if I had come across this meaning, I might not have suggested it.

Comment: I suppose that i should have edited the title to say, "Philosophically Selective" then.  However, considering that the body of the OP was primarily focused towards philosophy, i believe that the term suits it well.  Also, i should have probably left out the term, "Best" as that is completely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'discriminating'?

Here are some attested examples:

> a. Fraternities and sororities play a huge role in the student life of many Americans who attend higher education, providing an instant network of friends, and a vast network of contacts to make use of after graduation. The most “prestigious” student groups can be very **discriminating** in who they admit. ([The Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/yale-university-fraternity-brett-kavanaugh-george-bush-sexual-harassment-women-lawsuit-delta-kappa-a8776441.html))
>
> b. Here’s what developmental psychologists do know: Boys can be very **discriminating** when it comes to choosing a plaything. ([Slate Magazine](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2011/01/why-boys-like-sticks-the-explainer-s-2010-question-of-the-year.html))
>
> c. With so many selections of golds and silvers, a scenic artist or faux-finish painter can be very **discriminating** when selecting a metallic finish. ([Scenic Art for the Theatre: History, Tools and Techniques](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=joBZJjPoORIC&pg=PA398&dq=%22can%20be%20very%20discriminating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj00MmEntnhAhVBIIgKHTFIB28Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22can%20be%20very%20discriminating%22&f=false))